# What's the hibernate dialect for this driver/DB connection?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I just received some requirements to use Spring Boot/Spring DAta/JPA to connect into a DB. Here's the URL:

```
jdbc:compositesw:dbapi@XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX?domain=twccorp&dataSource=SFDC&connectTimeout=120
```

Here's the driver:

```
cs.jdbc.driver.CompositeDriver
```

Here's my application.properties (values ommitted for safety):

```
 spring.datasource.url = 'same as above'
 spring.datasource.username = xxxxxxx
 spring.datasource.password = xxxxxxx
 spring.datasource.driverClassName = 'same as above'
```

And the log here:

```
  o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=composite, majorVersion=7]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'
  2018-10-17 10:08:06.008  WARN 1232 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service
```

I would be thankful to someone which can give a light.

Comment: your error message is show to define spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= but not sure what is dialect name for CIS, did you added csjdbc jar as I dont think its listed in maven repo..

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue.

As composite specific dialect is not available, I've used `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` dialect.

It worked fine.